# Need help finding number of Thread Objects created in specific problem

Tags: java, multithreading

I was given this problem to solve.

> How many Thread objects are created when the code is compiled and run.

My answer would be 1 thread object which is `tc` because the `t` Thread array is empty. Also, I'm having a difficult time explaining the following instruction.

```
new Thread(tc.new Runner()).start();
```

Thanks for any help provided !

```
public class Test extends Thread {
    class Runner implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            Thread[] t = new Thread[5];
            for(int i = 0; i<t.length;i++) {
                System.out.println(t[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        Test tc = new Test();
        new Thread(tc.new Runner()).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Your code creates two thread _objects_. But only one of them is _started_. Though if we're being pedantic there's also the main thread that executes `main`, along with any other threads started as part of normal JVM operations.

Comment: The `Runner` class is an inner class (i.e. non-static nested class). Inner classes have implicit references to the enclosing class's instance, and therefore you need to specify which instance the inner class "belongs" to. That's what the `tc.new Runner()` bit does; it instantiates a `Runner` instance belonging to the `tc` instance. Note if you were not in a static context (e.g. an instance method of `Test`) then you could do `new Runner()` as that's implicitly equivalent to `this.new Runner()`.

Comment: @Slaw could you explain what's going on with the Thread array in the run method. Thanks again

Comment: The `Thread[] t = new Thread[5]` code is creating an _array_ of length `5` whose component type is `Thread`. That's all. Object arrays have their elements all initialized to `null` when first created and so no actual `Thread` objects are created there. That `for` loop will simply print out `null` five times.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you very much, you've been a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My answer would be 1 thread object which is tc because the t Thread array is empty

The answer is actually 2 threads.  The `Test` class extends thread so saying `new Test()` will also instantiate a `Thread`.  Then inside of `main` is a `new Thread(...)` call.  This is strange code (obviously an academic exercise) because the `Test` thread is never actually started or in any way needed.  Removing the `extends Thread` from `Test` would make the code work the same.

Also, there is the "main thread" that is running this code and I'm not sure if you are supposed to count that as well.

> I'm having a difficult time explaining the following instruction `new Thread(tc.new Runner()).start();`.

Let's break it down.

- You are created a new thread object and then calling the start method on it: `new Thread(...).start();`.
- The argument to the `Thread` constructor takes a `Runnable`.  In your case the `Runnable` is an instance of the `Runner` class.
- The `Runner` class is not `static` so to access it, you must have an enclosing instance of the `Test` class.
- The `tc.new Runnable(...)` does that for you.  However, it is a very infrequently used pattern and one that I have not seen in years.
- A better way to do this would be have a `startThread()` method in `Test` which creates the `Runner` instance and starts the thread.

Something like:

```
public class Test extends Thread {
   ...
   private class Runner implements Runnable { ... }
   private void startThread() {
       // maybe we should store this in a field so we can join later
       new Thread(new Runner()).start();
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test tc = new Test();
       tc.startThread();
   }
}
```

Lastly, it's important to realize that creating an array of objects does not create any instances of the objects themselves.

```
// no instances of Thread created here
Thread[] t = new Thread[5];
```